# Comparison of Riemannian metrics

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I was wondering precisely what is meant by the following statement. Given a manifold $\mathcal{M}$ and Riemannian metrics $g_1$ and $g_2$ on it, what is mean if one writes
\begin{equation}
g_1 \leq g_2.
\end{equation}

Is a comparison of eigenvalues? If so what is going on geometrically?

Comment: You'll need to give us a more exact context of where you saw this inequality, otherwise we are grasping at straws.

Comment: an example would be in Yau's Schwarz lemma

Answer (score 2):

This means that $g_1(v,v)\le g_2(v,v)$ for every tangent vector $v$.